# How can we find the IRR of cash flows in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, finance

I can easily find the NPV if items in a dataframe using the code below. But how can I get the IRR of the same items?

```
import numpy_financial as npf
import pandas as pd

# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':1000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':7000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'Casino'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

df.groupby("Building")["Revenue"].apply(lambda x: npf.npv(rate=0.1, values=x))
```

Result:

```
Building
Casino     24587.528174
Stadium    15773.854245
```

I tried to find the IRR, like this.

```
df.groupby("Building")["Revenue"].apply(lambda x: npf.irr(values=x))
```

It calculates only NAN.

Result:

```
Building
Casino    NaN
Stadium   NaN
```

Documentation: https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/latest/irr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am no expert on Financial Analysis, I believe this question requires more explanation and assessment than what has been presented.  So, with all due respect to @KarelZ's response which in fact produces an answer for the stated data, I think from a financial analysis standpoint it is not of much value.
As defined [Internal Rate of Return (IRR)](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=Internal+Rate+of+Return) is a metric used in financial analysis to estimate the profitability of potential investments. IRR is a discount rate that makes the net present value (NPV) of all cash flows equal to zero in a discounted cash flow analysis.  The inherent assumptions in this definition are (1) there exists an initial investment and (2) there is a cashflow stream resulting from the investment.

As defined [Net Present Value (NPV)](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=Net+Present+Value) is the present value of the cash flows at a specified rate of return of your project compared to your initial investment. In practical terms, it's a method of calculating your return on investment, or ROI, for a project or expenditure. While NPV doesn't necessarily imply an initial investment, it does imply that for the calculation to be useful, the true cashflow should be evaluated which implies taking into account the expenses as well as the revenue to be meaningful.

In order to compute a valid IRR we need to incorporate the initial investment in the structures and compute the IRR based on differences between Expenses and Revenue.  With this in mind, I have modified the original dataset by adding a row to each structure showing the initial investment as an Expense. See below:

```
# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Month': '2019-12-01', 'Expense':100000, 'Revenue':0, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':1000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':7000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2019-12-01', 'Expense':150000, 'Revenue':0, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'Casino'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This produces the dataframe shown below:

```
    Month   Expense Revenue Building
0   2019-12-01  100000  0   Stadium
1   2020-01-01  1000    5000    Stadium
2   2020-02-01  3000    4000    Stadium
3   2020-03-01  7000    5000    Stadium
4   2020-04-01  3000    4000    Stadium
5   2019-12-01  150000  0   Casino
6   2020-01-01  5000    6000    Casino
7   2020-02-01  5000    4000    Casino
8   2020-03-01  5000    9000    Casino
9   2020-04-01  6000    10000   Casino
```

To this dataframe I added a CashFlow Column consisting of the difference between expense and revenue as follows:

```
def computeCashFlow(e, r):
    return r-e  

df['CashFlow'] = df.apply(lambda row: computeCashFlow(row.Expense, row.Revenue), axis= 1)
```

Which results in the addition of the CashFlow shown below:

```
    Month   Expense Revenue Building    CashFlow
0   2019-12-01  100000  0   Stadium -100000
1   2020-01-01  1000    5000    Stadium 4000
2   2020-02-01  3000    4000    Stadium 1000
3   2020-03-01  7000    5000    Stadium -2000
4   2020-04-01  3000    4000    Stadium 1000
5   2019-12-01  150000  0   Casino  -150000
6   2020-01-01  5000    6000    Casino  1000
7   2020-02-01  5000    4000    Casino  -1000
8   2020-03-01  5000    9000    Casino  4000
9   2020-04-01  6000    10000   Casino  4000
```

Using the CashFlow Column you can then compute IRR and NPR as follows:

```
df.groupby("Building")["CashFlow"].apply(lambda x: npf.npv(rate=0.1, values=x))  
Building
Casino    -144180.042347
Stadium    -96356.806229
Name: CashFlow, dtype: float64  

df.groupby('Building')['CashFlow'].apply(lambda x: npf.irr(x))  
Building
Casino    -0.559380
Stadium   -0.720914
Name: CashFlow, dtype: float64
```

Giving realistic results for NPV and IRR taking into account the original investments

Comment: Thanks. What would you like to see improved regarding my answer? Use the aggregated CF between expenses and revenue instead of artificially adjusting the sign? I'll adjust it.

Comment: @KarelZ As I indicated, your answer provides a answer to the OP's question.  My answer was meant to address a larger problem related to the adequacy and validity of the OP's approach.  As illustrated in my suggested answer, to adequately address the analysis, the OP needed to recognize the initial investment and consider both revenue and expense as I did using the CF column.

Comment: I see. Your answer adresses some points, where I only provided a brief explanation. Might be helpful for others. I also updated my answer to also include aggregated cashflow.

Comment: Yeah, this analysis is much more robust than I was initially pondering. My original post was a bit naive. This solution from itprorh66 seems much more rigorous. Thanks for sharing your thoughts, itprorh66!!

Answer (score 1):

You could combine [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`irr()`](https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/latest/irr.html).

What you try to find is the interest rate, where the NPV is 0. However, as you only have positive revenues and no initial investment (neg. sign), it can not be. Please check out the formula used [in the docs](https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/latest/irr.html). You might want to also consider the expenses?

I've edited your example to demonstrate a working solution.

Update: I added large initial payments and passed the delta between expenses and revenue to `irr()`.

```
import numpy_financial as npf
import pandas as pd

data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':100000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':7000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':500000, 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'Casino'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

irr = df.groupby('Building')[['Revenue','Expense']].apply(lambda x: npf.irr(x['Revenue'] - x['Expense']))

print(irr)
```

**Output:**

```
Building
Casino    -0.786486
Stadium   -0.809623
dtype: float64
```